# 'Shape of passed values is x, indices imply y' pandas apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this bit of code:

```
def feat_ext_nir(x):
    img = loadImage(x['image_name'])
    compressed_img = compress_image(16, 16, img[:,:,3])
    return compressed_image.ravel()

cloud_feat_nir = cloud_df_samp.apply(feat_ext_nir, axis=1)
cloud_feat_nir.describe()
```

When I execute I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2000, 256), indices imply (2000, 5)
```

The apply function is supposed to be returning a new dataframe. The only information it is getting from the old dataframe (cloud_df_samp) is the column 'image_name'. 256 is the correct number of columns that should be returning, but it seems to think the number should be the same as the number of columns in cloud_df_samp (5) and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone tell me why it expects 5 columns or what I should do differently? Full error trace is:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2000, 256), indices imply (2000, 5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in 
create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, names, axes)
   4262         blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
-> 4263         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   4264         mgr._consolidate_inplace()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in 
__init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check, fastpath)
   2760         if do_integrity_check:
-> 2761             self._verify_integrity()
   2762 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in 
_verify_integrity(self)
   2970             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != 
mgr_shape[1:]:
-> 2971                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], 
self.axes)
   2972         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in 
construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   4232     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply 
{1}".format(
-> 4233         passed, implied))
   4234 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2000, 256), indices imply (2000, 5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c473d99817c3> in <module>()
  4     return compressed_image.ravel()
  5 
----> 6 cloud_feat_nir = cloud_df_samp.apply(feat_ext_nir, axis=1)
      7 cloud_feat_nir.describe()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, 
func, 
axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
```

Comment: What is the dtype of the 'image_name' column? ```cloud_df_samp['image_name'].dtype```. Also, do you require the feat_ext_nir() function to take a dataframe as input and output? Would it suffice to export the 'image_name' column to a numpy.ndarray to complete the transform? ```cloud_df_samp['image_name'].values```

Comment: The dtype of the 'image_name' column is object (it's a string). The reason I am trying to use dataframes as input and output is I am trying to preserve the indices. I eventually want to concat the output dataframe with the original. I could probably hack something together with ndarrays, but I am going for best practices.

Comment: That being said, working with ndarrays doesn't seem to be straightforward either. There doesn't seem to be a clean method of taking a 1d array and applying a function to get a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a shot in the dark as I'm not certain of the details of the input data, but does this code work as you'd wish?:

```
def feat_ext_nir(x):
    img = loadImage(x['image_name'])
    compressed_img = compress_image(16, 16, img[:,:,3])
    return compressed_image.ravel().tolist()

cloud_feat_nir = pd.Series(cloud_df_samp.apply(feat_ext_nir, axis=1))
cloud_feat_nir.describe()
```